# Adding minutes to LocalDateTime gives error on daylight saving days

Tags: java, localdatetime

I want to add minutes to a `LocalDateTime`, like this:

```
 public Timestamp addMinutes(long minutes, LocalDateTime recordDate) {
     LocalDateTime minAddedTime = recordDate.plusMinutes((long) minutes);
     return minAddedTime;
```

This gives an error on daylight saving dates.

For example my `localdatetime = 2021-10-31 02:00:00.0`,
`minutes = 1440` and return value should be `2021-11-01 01:00:00.0`. Instead I get `2021-11-01 02:00:00.0`.

How should I solve this?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is "local" i.e. it doesn't know anything about time zones and therefore it can't apply any daylight saving rules, as they differ all over the world. I think you should look at the `ZonedDateTime` class it can do what you want.

Comment: Alternatively, you can skip adding minutes on Java side, and construct an `INTERVAL` to use on SQL side (which is I assume what your `Timestamp` is about).

Comment: Thank you. Using ZonedDateTime zt = ldt.atZone() solved the problem.

Comment: @ArchanaHegde: If your problem is solved you should post the solution yourself and mark it as accepted. In that way readers can quickly seen that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used zoned date time to get right answer.

```
public Timestamp addMinutes(long minutes, Timestamp recordDate) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = recordDate.toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()); 
        LocalDateTime minAddedTime = zonedDateTime.plusMinutes(minutes).toLocalDateTime();
        return Timestamp.valueOf(minAddedTime);

    }
```